# Approximation by a polynomial in $C^1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that for any $f\in C^1[0,1]$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that
$$
|| f-P ||_{C^1[0,1]}<\epsilon,
$$
where
$$
\| g\|_{C^1[0,1]}=\|g\|_{C[0,1]}+\left\|\frac{dg}{dx}\right\|_{C[0,1]}.
$$

I would be thankful if somebody justifies the correctness of 
**My Try:**
Since $f' \in C[0,1] $, and since $[0,1]$ is compact, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $$||f'-Q||_{C[0,1]}  = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f'(x)-Q(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$  Therefore for any $x \in [0,1]$ we have $$|f'(x)-Q(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Rightarrow -\frac{\epsilon}{2}<f'(x)-Q(x)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$f'(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are continuous and bounded functions on $[0,x]$, therefore they are Riemann-integrable functions on $[0,x]$, for any $x \in [0,1]$. Therefore we have $$- \int^x_0 \frac{\epsilon}{2} dx <\int^x_0 f'(x) dx -\int^x_0 Q(x) dx < \int^x_0 \frac{\epsilon}{2} dx$$  $$- \frac{\epsilon}{2}x <f(x)-f(0) -\int^x_0 Q(x) dx <  \frac{\epsilon}{2} x $$ Let $P(x)$ be the polynomial $f(0)+\int^x_0 Q(x) dx$, Therefore $$|f(x)-P(x)| <  \frac{\epsilon}{2} x < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \ \ \ \forall x \in [0,1] \Rightarrow \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)-P(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \ \blacksquare $$

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Looks good too. You could start the integration from $Q$ to $P$ at the midpoint $x=\tfrac12$, i.e., set $P(\tfrac12)=f(\tfrac12)$, to get even tighter error bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct, but some people (myself included) would object to using $x$ simultaneously as a limit of integration and as a variable of integration, as in $$\int_0^x Q(x)\,dx$$ The flaw of this notation becomes apparent when you try to describe the region of integration by  inequalities: "$0\le x\le x$"? It can lead to other mix-ups, and is best avoided: write $$\int_0^x Q(t)\,dt$$ for example. Here the integration is over all $t$ such that $0\le t\le x$, which makes sense.