# Uniform convergence questions

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently studying for my analysis final and am really struggling with it. My professor won't be having office hours till closer to the exam date so I'm hoping I could get some help here. I'm trying to prove the following $\textbf{Question 1}$

Assume $(g_n(t))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of continuous functions in $C([0,T]), g_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly on $[0,T]$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$is uniformly continuous. Show that $f(g_n) \rightarrow f(g)$ uniformly on $[0,T]$

My solution: Since $g_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly, let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall \delta>0 $  $ |g_n(t)-g(t)|< \delta$ when $n \geq N$ $ \forall$$ t \in [0,T]$

Then by uniform continuity of $f$, $ \forall \epsilon >0$ $|f(g_n(t))-f(g(t))| < \epsilon$ when $|g_n(t)-g(t)|< \delta$ $\forall t \in [0,T]$

$\therefore f(g_n) \rightarrow f(g)$ uniformly

Could someone verify if this is correct?

Also having trouble with this $\textbf{Question 2}$:
Let $f \in C^1([0,1])$, with norm $||f||_{C^1} = ||f||_\infty + ||f'||_\infty$, where $C^1([0,1]) $ are the continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ with the property that $||f-p||_{C^1}<\epsilon$

$||f-p||_{C^1} = ||f-p||_\infty + ||(f-p)'||_\infty$. By Weierstrass Approximation theorem $\exists$ polynomial $p$ s.t $||f-p||_\infty< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

I'm not sure how to go about showing $||(f-p)'||_\infty< \frac{\epsilon}{2} $

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For your second one, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694621/approximation-by-a-polynomial-in-c1-norm) may help.

Answer (score 1):

For first problem your starting line isn't really correct:

$g_n\to g$ uniformly means for all $\delta>0$ there exist $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $|g_n(t)-g(t)|<\delta$ for all $t$. It's not that there is $N$ such that for all $\delta>0$ the property holds; $N$ depends on choice of $\delta$ not the other way around.

Apart from this conceptual error there isn't major problem with problem 1, but your writing style could be improved a bit further to make your implications clear.

---

For second problem, since $f'$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$ Weierstrass approximation gives you another polynomial $q$ such that $\|f'-q\|_{\infty}<\epsilon /2$

Let

$$
p(x)=\int_0^x q(t)\,dt + f(0)
$$

so $p(0)=f(0)$, $p'=q$.

Can you show that this $p$ satisfies required condition?

Comment: Thanks for the input! That p(x) function is clever, don't think I'd be able to come up with it on my own tho haha